# @Register or <controls />?

Tags: asp.net

Starting with .Net Framework 2.0 one might register custom controls for all pages with the controls element of web.config. From performance perspective is it more efficient to do so than using the <%@ Register element of an ASP.Net page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an efficiency standpoint, it would seem that using the controls element in web.config would be better, because it is cached once when the application starts; whereas the page directive `Register` will be processed every page request.

Comment: The Register directive isn't processed on each page request. It's just a hint for the aspx compiler. Once the aspx is compiled, it's not processed again until it changes or the site restarts.